# Julia: Even-number datatype for functions

Tags: julia

I have about 50 functions which should consume only even positive numbers. Right now I am checking each time with an "if" whether the number put in is zero or not:

```
function grof(x::Int)
    if (x % 2) == 0
        println("good")
    else
        throw("x is not an even number!!!!!!!!!!!!! Stupid programmer!")
    end
end
```

Ideally, I would like to have a datatype which produces this automatically, i.e.

```
function grof(x::EvenInt)
    println("good")  
end
```

However, I am not able to produce this datatype by my own since I am unable to understand the [documentary](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/index.html). Thanks for your help!

Best, v.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think creating a type is warranted in such a situation: I would simply [`@assert`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.@assert) that the condition is verified at the beginning of the function(s). (Funnily enough, checking the whether a number is even is the example that was chosen in the documentation to illustrate the effect of `@assert`)

For example:

```
julia> function grof(x::Int)
           @assert iseven(x) "Stupid programmer!"
           println("good")
       end
grof (generic function with 1 method)

julia> grof(2)
good

julia> grof(3)
ERROR: AssertionError: Stupid programmer!
Stacktrace:
 [1] grof(::Int64) at ./REPL[5]:2
 [2] top-level scope at REPL[7]:1
```

---

EDIT: If you **really** want to create a type enforcing such a constraint, it is possible. The way to do this would be to

1. create a type (possibly subtyping one of the `Number` abstract types; maybe `Signed`)
2. define an inner constructor ensuring that such a type cannot hold an odd value

A very simple example to build upon would be along the lines of:

```
# A wrapper around an even integer value
struct EvenInt
    val :: Int

    # inner constructor
    function EvenInt(val)
        @assert iseven(val)
        new(val)
    end
end

# Accessor to the value of an EvenInt
val(x::EvenInt) = x.val

# A method working only on even numbers
grof(x::EvenInt) = println("good: $(val(x)) is even")
```

You'd use this like so:

```
julia> x = EvenInt(42)
EvenInt(42)

julia> grof(x)
good: 42 is even

julia> y = EvenInt(1)
ERROR: AssertionError: iseven(val)
Stacktrace:
 [1] EvenInt(::Int64) at ./REPL[1]:5
 [2] top-level scope at REPL[6]:1
```

but note that you can't do anything on `EvenInt`s yet: you need to either unwrap them (using `val()` in this case), or define operations on them (a task which can be vastly simplified if you make `EvenInt` a subtype of one of the abstract number types and follow the relevant interface).

Comment: You looked disappointed, so I added an example showing how you could define such a type if you really wanted to.

Comment: This is not what the type system is for. In general, you want to use types for things that are easy to statically reason about. Reasoning statically about whether a value is even or not is sometimes possible, but generally not. In this case, checking for evenness is very cheap and clear. Why would getting a method error be preferable?

Answer (score 3):

All integers multiplied by two are even, so redefine your function to take half the number it currently takes.

```
function grof2(halfx::Int)
       x=2*halfx
       println("good")
end
```

Comment: Or even use that as the internal representation of `EvenInt`.