# Multiple dispatch in julia with the same variable type

Tags: julia

Usually the multiple dispatch in julia is straightforward if one of the parameters in a function changes data type, for example `Float64` vs `Complex{Float64}`. How can I implement multiple dispatch if the parameter is an integer, and I want two functions, one for even and other for odd values?

Comment: To my understanding, multiple dispatch is based on Type. You will need to set up conditionals in the function and not use Multiple Dispatch for this sort of thing.

Comment: This question is oddly similar to this one here that was asked recently: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61120716/julia-even-number-datatype-for-functions/61122219

Comment: Check my answer, I think it's a way cleaner than digging into specific types.

Answer (score 4):

You may be able to solve this with a `@generated` function: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/metaprogramming/#Generated-functions-1

But the simplest solution is to use an ordinary branch in your code:

```
function foo(x::MyType{N}) where {N}
    if isodd(N)
        return _oddfoo(x)
    else
        return _evenfoo(x)
    end
end
```

This may seem as a defeat for the type system, but if `N` is known at compile-time, the compiler will actually select *only* the correct branch, and you will get static dispatch to the correct function, without loss of performance.

This is idiomatic, and as far as I know the recommended solution in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

I expect that with type dispatch you ultimately still are calling after a check on odd versus even, so the most economical of code, without a run-time penatly, is going to be having the caller check the argument and call the proper function.

If you nevertheless have to be type based, for some reason unrelated to run-time efficiency, here is an example of such:

```
abstract type HasParity end

struct Odd <: HasParity
    i::Int64
    Odd(i::Integer) = new(isodd(i) ? i : error("not odd"))
end

struct Even <: HasParity
    i::Int64
    Even(i::Integer) = new(iseven(i) ? i : error("not even"))
end

parity(i) = return iseven(i) ? Even(i) : Odd(i)

foo(i::Odd) = println("$i is odd.")
foo(i::Even) = println("$i is even.")


for n  in 1:4
    k::HasParity = parity(n)
    foo(k)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

So here's other option which I think is cleaner and more multiple dispatch oriented (given by a coworker). Let's think `N` is the natural number to be checked and I want two functions that do different stuff depending if `N` is  even or odd. Thus

```
boolN = rem(N,2) == 0
(...)
function f1(::Val{true}, ...)
(...)
end
function f1(::Val{false}, ...)
(...)
end
```

and to call the function just do

```
f1(Val(boolN))
```

Answer (score 0):

As @logankilpatrick pointed out the dispatch system is type based. What you are dispatching on, though, is well established pattern known as a trait.

Essentially your code looks like

```
myfunc(num) = iseven(num) ? _even_func(num) : _odd_func(num)
```

Comment: What you describe here is not a trait: it is merely a (user-written) run-time check dispatching on one of two implementations. Traits rely on the type system to implement a form of polymorphism orthogonal to the inheritance tree. See for example this [blog post](https://www.juliabloggers.com/the-emergent-features-of-julialang-part-ii-traits/) for an introduction to traits.